# create multi support screen with psd file

Tags: android, imageview, photoshop, multiscreen

i want to use an `imageview` in my android application. but i don't know in which sizes i should design with photoshop to supporting multi screen sizes and densities?
also i put this codes in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

can anybody say me what `px*px` should i design my picture for `imageview`??
tnx alot